# TCP socket on server is getting closed/not showing in LISTEN state

Tags: java, jacorb

I am facing the problem regarding socket close. I am able to create the socket and everything is working fine for some extent of time. When I try to connect to server, my clients are connecting and performing all the operations well. But after some hours the state of the socket is not showing in **LISTEN** mode. So that all the clients are stopped performing their functions and getting error as "**could not connect to "server_ip:port_no"**".
I am not getting what exactly is happening. I am using **jacorb API** for this.

Without calling **close()** on socket it is getting terminated. Why the port is not showing in listen mode? I have checked the status of the port using command **"netstat -anp | gerp port_no"**.

Comment: Maybe your application just crashed (e.g. out of memory)?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, a server's listening port has a finite number of allowable connections, and when all of them have been granted to connection requests coming from the clients, the listen port will be pulled so that any new connection request will be denied.  It looks like that was what have happened to your server.  To "see" the listen port again, the client needs to release the connections to the listen port when they are no longer needed.